# How to read color of text in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

How why do I not find the color of this text in the right side?

[image]

Comment: My complete and utter guess would be the "Fills" area.

Comment: Where is that? :) I do not see. When I press that in the right column, it will recolor this red text to gray.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not a Sketch user. I was literally just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Fills section on the right side under the "DESIGN" tab.

[Official documentation: Fills](https://www.sketch.com/docs/designing/styling/fills/)

I marked the area below in red.

[image: Fills]